# How to perform a cell deselection when a user returns to a table view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using a UITableView to display a list of cells, when the user selects a cell then a new view appears by using the following code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailsViewController animated: TRUE];
}
```

By using the code above, the view is displayed correctly, but when I return back to the root table view, then the cell is still selected.
I noticed, in many sdk examples, that the cell is deselected (with a nice animation) when the root view is poped pack, but I could not find the code that implemented this feature in any of the examples.
I know that I can use:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];
```

to implement this, but I am very curious on how these examples do it without using any code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` automatically handles this for you when you call `super` in `viewDidAppear:` etc.  So the easiest way to achieve this is to subclass UITableViewController.  If you can't (e.g. because the table is just a part of a more complex view), then you'll have to do it yourself in the `viewDidAppear:` method.  (You should also flash the scrollers, too).